# Make overlay of figures css

Tags: css, overlay

I have the following picture:

[image]

It has a dark gray background and above a kind of overlay of figures. ( like a diamonds )

I wonder if the overlay of figures can be done by CSS?

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: *dark gray background and above a kind of overlay of figures.* i cant see the figures

Comment: the figures are like a diamonds or rhombus

Comment: if `diamonds` or `rhombus` is created with html/css then i think it is possbile can you show your html/css of `diamonds` or `rhombus` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index. `z-index:int;` (int being a number ofc) 
Higher values will show above / cover other objects with smaller values.  
This tag is quite basic so I'm not sure if it's what you want.

Comment: ok. but the object that cover the background gray, this object, can be done by css ? this is my question..

Comment: As far as I know, it cannot, but you can use the html `<canvas>` tag.[A website about canvases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) EDIT: removed attempt of link using <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

Create an image of a single, repeatable rectangle, then use something like the following CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

[MDN Documentation for `background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).

Comment: @user3810167 This is probably the easiest way, You could look into CSS 3 gradients and transforms though.

Answer (score 0):

Today I'm creating a overlay image for above problem

There is two files:
1. Overlay.html
2. Overlay.css

STEPS:
1. In Overlay.html, creating a link for overlay imageby below code:

```
<a href="#overlay"><img src="images/angularjs.png"></a>
```

2. In above tag there is an id(#overlay).
3. By click on this overlay image is display by below code:

   X
4. In overlay.css file type below code:

   ```
   .overlay {
            position: fixed;               /* This property is fixed the image on overlay  */
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(10, 10, 200, 0.8);        /* For giving background color and opticity  */
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
           -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
       }


   .overlay:target {
       opacity:1;
               pointer-events: auto;
       }


   .overlay > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
           padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
           border-radius: 10px;
           }
   ```
5. In last step , .close css class in created:
               .close {
                   background: red;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                   line-height: 25px;
                   position: absolute;
                   right: -12px;
                   text-align: center;
                   top: -10px;
                   width: 24px;
                   text-decoration: none;
                   font-weight: bold;
                   -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
                   -moz-border-radius: 12px;
                   border-radius: 12px;
                   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
           }

   ```
       .close:hover {
            background: #00d9ff;
         }
   ```

Html File:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Overlay Images</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    </head>
    <<a href="#overlay"><img src="images/angularjs.png"></a>

      <div id="overlay" class="overlay">
          <div> 
             <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
             <img src="images/angularjs.jpg">
           </div>
      </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

CSS File:

```
      .overlay {
             position: fixed;
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
             top: 0;
             right: 0;
             bottom: 0;
             left: 0;
             background: rgba(10, 10, 200, 0.8);
             z-index: 99999;
             opacity:0;
             -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
             -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
              transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
              pointer-events: none;
          }


      .overlay:target {
               opacity:1;
               pointer-events: auto;
                 }



        .overlay > div {
                   width: 400px;
                   position: relative;
                   margin: 10% auto;
                   padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
                   border-radius: 10px;
               }


          .close {
                background: red;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                line-height: 25px;
                position: absolute;
                right: -12px;
                text-align: center;
                top: -10px;
                width: 24px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
                -moz-border-radius: 12px;
                 border-radius: 12px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
               }
                 .close:hover {
                     background: #00d9ff;
                       }
```